# Weight and bias initialization in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm doing some electricity load forecasting in which I want to initialize the weight and bias. I have calculated weight and bias using different algorithms and saved it in a file. I want to use that file and start my training using those weight and biases.

Here is the code which I want to update.

```
#RNN designning
tf.reset_default_graph()

inputs = 1  #input vector size
hidden = 100    
output = 1  #output vector size

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_periods, inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_periods, output])


basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=hidden, activation=tf.nn.relu)
rnn_output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

learning_rate = 0.001   #small learning rate so we don't overshoot the minimum

stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, hidden])           #change the form into a tensor
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, output)        #specify the type of layer (dense)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, num_periods, output])          #shape of results

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))    #define the cost function which evaluates the quality of our model
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)          #gradient descent method
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)          #train the result of the application of the cost_function                                 

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()           #initialize all the variables
epochs = 1000     #number of iterations or training cycles, includes both the FeedFoward and Backpropogation
mape = []

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

y_pred = {'NSW': [], 'QLD': [], 'SA': [], 'TAS': [], 'VIC': []}

for st in state.values():
    print("State: ", st, end='\n')
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
        init.run()
        for ep in range(epochs):
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: x_batches[st], y: y_batches[st]})
            if ep % 100 == 0:
                mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: x_batches[st], y: y_batches[st]})
                print(ep, "MSE:", mse)
        y_pred[st] = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: x_batches_test[st]})
    print("\n")
```

I'm finding the weights and biases using following algo and saving it in `weights` and `biases` as a list of list.

```
class network:
    def set_weight_bias(self, a):
        lIt = 0
        rIt = 0
        self.weights = []
        self.biases = []
        for x,y in zip(self.sizes[1:], self.sizes[:-1]):
            rIt += x*y
            self.weights.append(a[lIt:rIt].reshape((x,y)))
            lIt = rIt
        for x in self.sizes[1:]:
            rIt += x
            self.biases.append(a[lIt:rIt].reshape((x,1)))
            lIt = rIt

    ...
    """
    Cuckoo Search Optimization
    """

    def objectiveFunction(self,x):
        self.set_weight_bias(x)
        y_prime = self.feedforward(self.input)
        return sum(abs(u-v) for u,v in zip(y_prime, self.output))/x.shape[0]

    def cso(self, n, x, y, function, lb, ub, dimension, iteration, pa=0.25,
                 nest=100):
        """
        :param n: number of agents
        :param function: test function
        :param lb: lower limits for plot axes
        :param ub: upper limits for plot axes
        :param dimension: space dimension
        :param iteration: number of iterations
        :param pa: probability of cuckoo's egg detection (default value is 0.25)
        :param nest: number of nests (default value is 100)
        """
        ...
```

I want to use custom weights and biases to start my training instead of randomly assigned weights and biases by tensorflow. How to do that in tensorflow?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DocDriven I want to use custom weights and biases to start my training instead of randomly assigned weights and biases by tensorflow. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to set weights for the RNN Cell or for the Dense layer? If it's for the RNN cell, you should be able to set the weights using the [set_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicRNNCell#set_weights) method.

If it's for the [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) layer, you should be able to assign a [`Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) and use the `initializer` argument to pass your weights (and another for the bias'). Then, when you call `layers.dense`, you can pass both your variable tensors to `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer` for weights and biases respectively.

Comment: How to use `tf.get_variable()` as `initializer`? I've got a list of numpy array as weights and biases.

Comment: Use [```tf.constant_initializer(numpy_array)```](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer) as the initializer argument in ```tf.get_variable()```

Answer (score 1):

For each layer, you can refer the documentation to see how the initialization is done:

- Call the `set_weights` function on the BasicRNNCell ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicRNNCell#set_weights))
- Pass a function that returns the initial weight to the `kernel_initializer`, and one that returns the initial bias to the `bias_initializer` while creating the dense layer ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense))

Comment: How to use a list of numpy array as `kernel_initializer`?